# How to check textbox text changed

Tags: .net, wpf, uibutton

i have a textbox of label "NAME" i need to disable the a button(that is next Button) as long as this textbox is empty.
this is my appproach

```
private void planName_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (planName.Text.Length != 0)
        {
            parent.EnableOrDisableNextButton("enable") ;
        }
    }
```

this is working for first time but if user again clear the name then next button remain enable s or if he cut the whole field.
how to get this?

Comment: Passing around strings instead of booleans strikes me as a bad idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable it with else:

```
        private void planName_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) 
        { 
            if (planName.Text.Length != 0) 
            { 
                parent.EnableOrDisableNextButton("enable"); 
            } 
            else
                parent.EnableOrDisableNextButton("disable");
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

This could be done more easily in XAML with a binding by the way:

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding Text.Length, ElementName=planName}" .../>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are only enabling your button, i.e. when condition `planName.Text.Length != 0` is met your code is executed and button gets enabled, however when condition is not met nothing is actioned and button remains enabled.